# ¿Qué podemos hacer con una pregunta basada en opiniones que tiene una respuesta elaborada?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica

Ayer, surgió la pregunta [¿Cuál es la librería de gráficos más eficiente en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304410/cual-es-la-librer%C3%ADa-de-gr%C3%A1ficos-mas-eficiente-en-javascript). Claramente esta basada en opiniones, pero dio lugar a una respuesta elaborada. Además [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/304525/83) no responde realmente a lo que se pregunta.

Ha habido un pequeño debate sobre ella en el chat, y el usuario @Israel-González, que no quiere que se pierda esta respuesta, ha creado otra pregunta para que coincida con lo que responde la anterior (Para que el OP de la respuesta la pueda cambiar de sitio a una pregunta que coincida). Israel estaba dispuesto a borrar su pregunta, pero yo le he insistido en que no lo haga, que solo era mi opinión y que igual no estaba en lo correcto.

La intención de este usuario me parece muy buena, pero creo que la forma de mantener esta respuesta no es la correcta. Por lo que traigo esta discusión a Meta.

En mi criterio y siguiendo lo que he visto y las normas de SOes, creo que se podría hacer lo siguiente, ordenado de lo que creo que es mas correcto para el sitio a menos.

- Traducir esta pregunta y respuesta a [Software Recommendations de Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). (Como sugiere @Ordago en el comentario de la pregunta original).
- Modificar la pregunta original (con consentimiento del OP), para que la respuesta sea valida a esa pregunta. (Esto no arreglaría el problema de que sea basada en opiniones.)
- Realizar otra pregunta para que coincida con la respuesta (El caso de Israel)
- Alguna otra opción que no se me haya ocurrido

Comment: En mi opinión, esta pregunta/respuesta no puede tener cabida en el sitio nunca. Pongamos que yo me pongo a discutir uno o varios de los datos expuestos en la respuesta, como por ejemplo lo que el autor de la respuesta considera un pro, para mi puede ser un contra. Podríamos engancharnos en una discusión sin final. Por ello, en el sitio no se admiten preguntas que puedan estar basadas en opiniones.

Comment: @Pikoh interesante. De todos modos, ¿y si la pregunta fuera algo así? _¿Qué diferencias más importantes hay entre Angular y React?_ Para mí esta última sí podría tener mejor cabida.

Comment: @fedorqui si esa fuera la pregunta, la respuesta de la que se habla tampoco encajaría. De todas maneras, para mi sería algo mejor esa pregunta, pero seguiría sin encajar. Por un lado, podría obtener una respuesta demasiado amplia (las diferencias pueden ser infinitas), y por otro cuando se habla de _diferencias_ es complicado no valorar esas diferencias de forma positiva o negativa. Yo sigo sin verlo... :)

Comment: Pensandolo mejor, de hecho ni siquiera la pregunta: _Cuáles son las principales caracteristicas de Angular_ terminaría de encajarme en el sitio, cuánto menos una hablando de diferencias entre dos frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Una pregunta sobre "más eficiente" puede volverse una pregunta apropiada para el sitio describiendo los criterios para determinar que algo es más eficiente que otras alternativas, pero esto en gran medida depende del AP. Si en comentarios ha aclarado a qué se refiere con más eficiente y en particular ha explicado un problema específico a resolver, la pregunta podría editarse para resolver el que sea basada en opiniones, no importa si eso lo ha hecho en comentarios a la pregunta, a la respuesta o en el chat.

Por otro lado, si una pregunta "off-topic" inspira un pregunta "on-topic" me parece muy válido hacer la publicación, pero publicar una pregunta para copiar la respuesta que está "fuera de lugar" podría ser válido si el autor de la respuesta fuera el que hiciera la copia para luego borrar la respuesta original. Si el autor de la respuesta "desaparece", podría analizarse el caso con mayor atención.

Comment: Creo que con la modificación de titulo de fedorqui se ha podido malinterpretar la pregunta. Pero esta mas enfocado a este caso en particular por eso puse la etiqueta de pregunta-especifica y no en general

Answer (score 1):

Como comento en la pregunta, y estando totalmente de acuerdo con el comentario de Pikoh, considero que la pregunta y la respuesta son basadas en opiniones, y difícilmente pueden ser salvadas.

Por lo que no creo que este sea el lugar adecuado para la pregunta y creo que la mejor manera de no perder el trabajo de la respuesta del OP sea traducir esta a (Si el OP quiere/puede o si quiere delegar la traduccion y alguien se quiere encargar) [Software Recommendations de Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) de esta manera aun que no sirva directamente a SOes pueda ayudar a mas gente.